# Mount window's CIFS share on RHAT7

Tags: linux, rhel, mount, cifs

I have had such situation: window's CIFS has already been mounted to `/home/external/backup` directory on Linux(RHAT7).

Also, I have configured some backup system that has stored files into `/home/backup` directory. Now I can't change the path for the backup.
CIFS mount directory can't be changed too.

Is there any ability to mount CIFS directory to the exisiting `home/backup` directory so that the backups can be stored in CIFS directory?

Comment: Unmount it and remount it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to unmount and then remount CIFS directory to the directory where backup files are stored using such commands as:

## unmount CIFS directory:

> `umount /mnt`

## mount CIFS directory to the folder where the backups are stored:

> `mount -t cifs -o username=<share user>,password=<share password> //WIN_PC_IP/<share name> /home/backup`

Answer (score 2):

you can look that up on redhats knowlegebase: [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/448263)

> Windows share can be mounted on RHEL system using cifs option of mount command as :

```
[root@host ~]# mount -t cifs -o username=<share user>,password=<share password> //WIN_PC_IP/<share name> /mnt
```

> In case your user is in windows domain then you can define the domain
>   as follows:

```
[root@host ~]# mount -t cifs -o username=<share user>,password=<share password>,domain=example.com //WIN_PC_IP/<share name> /mnt
```

**EDIT**
If Cifs Support is missing try running

> yum install cifs-utils

Comment: Welcome to USE! When referring to external sites for solution, you should always quote/summarise the solution in your answer so that when the link will break (it will) your answer would still have all the required information. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for more on how to write good answers.